# Is the reasoning in this proof correct regarding subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

This doesn't have all the symbols and l want to verify if my reasoning is sound. It is also one half of the iff proof.

Given : The union of X and Y is a subspace of V.

I have to prove that either X is contained in Y or Y is contained in X.

Reasoning :

Suppose there exists w belonging to X which doesn't belong to Y and there exists v belonging to Y which doesn't belong to X. Both w,v belong to the union of X and Y .  Let z= w+v.  z doesn't belong to the union of X and Y. Hence, the union of X and Y is not a subspace. This is a contradiction. Therefore, all w belonging to X, must also belong to Y or all v belonging to Y must belong to X.

I am not sure about z not belonging to the union in all cases but l can think of some particular examples.

I think this prove is very weak if not wrong and l will check better ones.

Comment: You have to *prove* that $z\notin X\cup Y$.  Do it by contradiction.

Comment: @saulspatz Any hint on that.

Comment: If $z\in X\cup Y$ then either $x\in X$ or $z\in Y$.  Suppose $z\in X$.   Then $v=z-w\in X$ contradiction.

Comment: @saulspatz Got it, thanks a lot. I wish l wasn't this slow.

Comment: I know what you mean; join the club.